# Gradle Version Conflict When Building Android Project in Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Tags: android, gradle

I am using Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 2 to create a new Android project with an empty activity. When building the project within Android Studio, everything works fine. However, when I try to run `./gradlew wrapper` from the command line, I encounter the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring the root project 'Addfree QR Scanner'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0'.

   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.4.0
      > No matching variant of com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0'.
```

My `gradle-wrapper-properties` file has the following content:

```
#Mon Nov 06 13:22:09 CET 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

In my project, I have configured Java 17.

Here is my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
}
```

I'm trying to understand where this version `8.2.1` is coming from, as it seems to conflict with my configuration. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I do not understand why the build is successful, the app runs on my phone, but the command "./gradlew wrapper" fails. I need it to work, as I'm attempting to set up "fastlane" and encountering the same error message. Please note that this issue occurs with a completely new project created within Android Studio.

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your gradles files?

Comment: "com.android.application" change version 8.1.1

Comment: if not solved after check sourceCompatibility and  targetCompatibility version JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8  and jvmTarget 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully resolved the issue. It turns out that configuring the Java version for Gradle is effective only when working on builds within Android Studio.

Here's the evidence:

[image: Check this image]

However, when I attempted to execute the `./gradlew wrapper` command in the command line, I encountered the error described in the original question.

To address this, I took the following steps:

1. I installed Java 17 on my Windows machine.
2. I ensured that the environment variables pointed to the newly installed Java 17, as shown here:

[image: Take a look at this image]

In summary, this means that configuring the Gradle JDK within Android Studio exclusively influences builds executed through Android Studio. If you plan to run Gradle commands manually in the terminal, it's essential to have Java 17 installed on your Windows machine, with the correct environment variables set up. Please note that a Windows restart may be required for the changes in environment variables to take effect.